# React.js cant itterate through an array with .map from useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project I collect input from a user in a simple form, I then want to save that input in an array of object setup through useState.  I update, the state, and I can see the objects when I print the state, but if I need a specific peice of data, I can not get that.

The form(collects users input):

```
<input id='foodText' type="text" />
<select id='unitBox'>
    {UnitsArray.map(unit=>(
        <option>{unit}</option>
        ))}
    </select>
    <input id='FoodAmount' type='number' />
    <button onClick={props.click} type="submit">Add</button>
```

The props.click as well as the useState(both of these are in the main app.js file)

```
const [FoodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);

const Foodie = () =>{
setFoodList([...FoodList,{'Item':document.getElementById('foodText').value,
        'Unit':document.getElementById('unitBox').value,
        'Quantity':parseInt(document.getElementById('FoodAmount').value)}])
console.log('changed')
}
```

And finally, this is when I use array.map() to itterate through it

```
useEffect(()=>{props.aId.map(food=>(console.log({food})))},[props.aId]);
useEffect(()=>{props.aId.map(food=>(console.log({food['Item']})))},[props.aId]);
//this will throw an exception error when I run it.
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `//this will throw an exception error` <-- which exception? Did you try to `console.log` `props.aId` to check its value?

Comment: My bad, I thought I added that.  It is a parsing error:
'Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","'

Comment: why are you using `document.getElementById('FoodAmount').value` to set the state can't you use state instead?

Comment: `Unexpected token` means you do not respect the JS syntax. Use an IDE or any tool to validate your code.`Unexpected token` means you do not respect the JS syntax. Use an IDE or any tool to validate your code. If I were you, I would try `console.log({food['Item']})` --> `console.log(food['Item'])`, Not sure if you can do that and which value it will take for the key...

Comment: `{food['Item']}` is not a valid way to construct an object

Answer (score 1):

First, it is always easier if the component is controlled.

```
const [foodText, setFoodText] = useState('');
const [unitBox, setUnitBox] = useState('');
const [foodAmount, setFoodAmount] = useState(0);

<input 
 id='foodText' 
 value={foodText} 
 onChange={(e) =>setFoodText(e.target.value)} 
 type="text" 
/>

<select id='unitBox' value={unitBox} onChange={(e) => setUnitBox(e.target.value)}>
    {UnitsArray.map(unit=>(
        <option>{unit}</option>
        ))}
</select>
<input 
 id='FoodAmount' 
 type='number' 
 value={foodAmount} 
 onChange={(e) =>setFoodAmount(e.target.value)} 
/>
<button onClick={props.click} type="submit">Add</button>
```

When your component is controlled you don't have to reach out to the DOM to get the value.

```
const Foodie = () =>{
setFoodList([...FoodList,{
        'Item':foodText,
        'Unit':unitBox,
        'Quantity':foodAmount
       }])

console.log('changed')
}
```

And finally: (just editing whatever you are trying to do)

```
useEffect(()=>{
 props.aId.map(food=> console.log(food))
},[props.aId]);

useEffect(()=>{
 props.aId.map(food=> console.log(food.Item))
},[props.aId]);
```